# How to override Material UI .MuiContainer-maxWidthLg?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, overriding

I'm trying to get rid of max-width that present in the theme.
This is what I see in Chrome (and if I uncheck it, it does what I need):

```
@media (min-width: 1280px)
.MuiContainer-maxWidthLg {
    max-width: 1280px;
}
```

How can I do this? 
I tried something like this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {       
        '& .MuiContainer-maxWidthLg' : {
             maxWidth: //No matter what I put here, it does not work
        },
```

but it does not seem to have any effect...
How can I override this?

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: can I see your code?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I've managed to override it by setting the following in a parent element:    '& .MuiContainer-maxWidthLg' : {
          maxWidth: '100%'
    },

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `maxWidth` prop of `Container` [defaults to 'lg'](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.13/packages/material-ui/src/Container/Container.js#L77), but you can prevent Material-UI trying to control the max width of the `Container` by setting `maxWidth={false}`.

Here's a simple example:

```
import React from "react";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Container maxWidth={false}>
      <Paper>
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      </Paper>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Container maxWidth]

Related documentation: https://material-ui.com/api/container/#props

Code reference: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.13/packages/material-ui/src/Container/Container.js#L88

Comment: missed this reading the docs, thank you!

Answer (score 10):

Well, in 22.11.2021 work like this

```
<Container sx={{ maxWidth:'100%'  }} maxWidth={false} >
```

Comment: This answers the question better.

Answer (score 4):

The values below can be filled to your needs accordingly if material UI provided defaults don't suit you well.

```
    const theme = createMuiTheme({
      breakpoints: {
        values: {
          xs: ,
          sm: ,
          md: ,
          lg: ,
          xl: ,
          xxl:
        }
      }
    });
    
    export default theme;


//And add to app.js

import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import theme from "style/theme";

 <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    //yourCode
 </ThemeProvider>
```

Comment: Please add a explanation for your code snipped. Just code isn't that meaningful then with explanation.

Comment: This should be added to container styleOverrides

Answer (score 3):

If you want further customization of the `lg` breakpoint, this snippet might help. I'm following the global theme overrides guide here: https://mui.com/customization/theme-components/

This works for **MUI 5.4.3**

```js
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

let theme = createTheme({});
theme = createTheme(theme, {
    components: {
        MuiContainer: {
            styleOverrides: {
                maxWidthLg: {
                    [theme.breakpoints.up('lg')]: {
                        maxWidth: // Your custom value here
                    },

                    // Note that you can customize other properties here, like padding, color, .etc.
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

You can still achieve this with `makeStyles`:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up('lg')]: {
      maxWidth: <YourMaxWidth>px,
    },
  },
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either turn off the `maxWidth` prop and change the element's width directly using `sx` or use the `ThemeProvide` to customize different width options globally.

```
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import Link from '@mui/material/Link/Link';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack/Stack';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import * as React from 'react';
import './style.css';

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiContainer: {
      styleOverrides: {
        maxWidthMd: {
          maxWidth: 320,
        },
        maxWidthLg: {
          maxWidth: 500,
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      {/* Customize component's width directly */}
      <Container
        maxWidth={false}
        sx={{ maxWidth: '200px'}}
      >
        <Stack spacing={2} direction="row">
          <Link>Home</Link>
          <Link>About</Link>
          <Link>Contact</Link>
        </Stack>
      </Container>

      {/* Use built-in maxWidth options with theme customization */}
      <Container maxWidth="md">
        <Stack spacing={2} direction="row">
          <Link>Home</Link>
          <Link>About</Link>
          <Link>Contact</Link>
        </Stack>
      </Container>
      <Container maxWidth="lg">
        <Stack spacing={2} direction="row">
          <Link>Home</Link>
          <Link>About</Link>
          <Link>Contact</Link>
        </Stack>
      </Container>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Here is a detailed article on how to override MUI container width: https://muhimasri.com/blogs/how-to-override-material-ui-container-width

Answer (score 0):

Well, setting the following in a parent div worked:

```
'& .MuiContainer-maxWidthLg' : {
      maxWidth: '100%'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the global approach, and had to add "!important" to get it to work:

```
const theme = createTheme({
    components: {
        MuiContainer: {
            styleOverrides: {
                root: {
                    maxWidth: '1440px'
                },
                maxWidthMd: {
                    maxWidth: 320,
                },
                maxWidthLg: {
                    maxWidth: '1440px!important',
                },
            },
        },
    },
```

mui-emotion has a `max-width: 1200` that needed to be over-ridden.