# How to set maxWidth of Container to 100% >> Globally

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Whenever I use a container in material-ui, I have to manually set the maxWidth to false. Since I don't think I will ever require the maxWidth of the container to every be anything but 100% of the available space and it is what I expect container to work, I wanted to set it globally in my react app.

What I have to do every time

```
import React from "react";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Container maxWidth={false}>
    .
    .
    .
    </Container>
  );
}
```

I tried setting it in the createTheme, but it does not work.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
      overrides: {
        MuiContainer: {
          root: {
            maxWidth: `100%`,
          },
        },
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of trying to override the CSS, the simplest approach is to set the default for the prop:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  props: {
    MuiContainer: {
      maxWidth: false
    }
  }
});
```

[image: Edit Container maxWidth in theme]

Related answers:

- [Is it possible to override material-ui components default props?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57359439/is-it-possible-to-override-material-ui-components-default-props/57360023#57360023)
- [How to override Material UI .MuiContainer-maxWidthLg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61633192/how-to-override-material-ui-muicontainer-maxwidthlg/61637432#61637432)

Comment: Great !!! Thanks a lot. I tried to do the same (setting maxWidth to false) but in "overrides" instead of props. I didn't know that your could set props globally for components. Thanks for the links provided too, very helpful.